# {{this}} inside {{#each}} --- Can't get {{this.val}} data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I can't get {{this.username}}

when I do:

```
{{#each history}}
    {{this.username}}   <!--THIS WILL NOT SHOW ANYTHING - OBJ in history->
    {{this}}     <!-- Shows data just fine, but cant get to any values like line above -->
{{/each}}

{{this}}   <!-- THIS WILL SHOW ARRAY OF OBJECTS OK
```

{{history}}    alone outputs this:

```
{ _id: 59fe71a6167aaa05f4dcf43c,
  userid: 'asd',
  name: 'asd',
  email: 'asd@asd.com',
  passwords: 'asd',
  product: 'asd',
  issues: 'asd',
  serial: 'asd',
  accessories: 'asdddddddd',
  __v: 0 }
{ _id: 59fe8c8c49830e09d82de3f1,
  userid: 'asd',
  name: 'asd',
  email: 'asd@gmagoaimg.com',
  passwords: 'sdfgasdg',
  product: 'afafafa',
  issues: 'fasfasf',
  serial: 'asdfa3a3fasfe',
  backedup: 'on',
  accessories: 'asdfgasdf',
  __v: 0 }
{ _id: 59fe8f26703bf10a2a985f10,
  userid: 'asd',
  name: 'Homer Gomez',
  email: 'ajsidfaos@faksdofa.com',
  passwords: 'asdfasdf',
  product: 'This is the product',
  issues: 'This is the prod desc',
  serial: 'afjdofajosdf98988',
  backedup: 'on',
  accessories: 'asdfasdf',
  __v: 0 }
```

etc...

Now, my route sends over the data,

```
router.get('/service_history', function(req, res) {
//compares req['user'].name with the Job.userid if the same:
    req['user'].service_history = []; // clears the user history
    Job.find()
      .then( function(doc){
        //console.log(doc);
        doc.forEach(function(job){
          //if (err) throw err
          if(job.userid == req['user'].name){
            console.log(job);
            req['user'].service_history.push(job);
          }
        });  
      }); 
      res.render('service_history', { history: {data: req['user'].service_history} }    );
});
```

: {{history}}
and when I render the page of this handlebars code, I can render the objects that I have pasted above in this post, above,

{{#each history}}

Thanks for any feedback, and sorry again for the newbish needs

Comment: I think your problem is that you are trying to access a non-existing attribute of history. Try ‘{{this.name}}‘ instead of ‘{{this.username}}‘

Comment: In the Handlebars docs there's no mention about using `this`. Try simply `{{#each history}}{{name}}{{/each}}` and you also have no `username` property in the history objects so why are you trying to access non-existing property?

Comment: Sorry guys, I was unclear with a non-existant-not-literally-in-my-code example. I verified this morning, when I change it to an existing value such as email, I get the same results.

To clarify by literal example:

I have this code in the handlebars file to show: 

EACH-W-NO-THIS no show
{{#each history}}
   {{email}}
{{/each}}

<br>

JUST-HISTORY
{{history}} - outputs just [obj-Obj]

<br>

EACH-W-THIS - Shows each Object literally with all of the Objs data
{{#each history}}  
 {{this}}
{{/each}}


Still can't get a value, even when using an existing required value. hmm

Comment: I want to thank you guys for the fast response and the time taken to send me an answer.  You are absolutely right, but this is a little deeper than what was presented. 

It was my Schema declared as [String], a String array, but was trying to jam in {Obj} ... It wasn't pushing to array. Also console output for the Obj I showed with the right data, was out of scope, and showed Objs before the push. So my bad on the output info. Got this squared away and getting individual values through this method:

{{#each history}}
 {{#each this}}
  {{email}}
  {{name}}
 {{/each}}
{{/each}}
THANKS!

Comment: The way I structured the returning json had a nested value that was un-needed and with current example code, would need an embedded loop to get to the elements, but restructured the output JSON and can use only one loop now to get the data I need.

Comment: Basically removing {data:  and the tailing }    ... this was overkill to say the least.